# Endnotes and headers

Tags: endnotes

I've to put the endnotes at the end of each chapter. This is the code for a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

% notes
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand\enoteformat{%
   \noindent\theenmark.\ \hangindent 0\parindent%
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\theendnotes}{%
  \renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textsuperscript{\theenmark}\enspace}%
}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Note} % <-------------------------------------
\let\footnote=\endnote
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}

% headers
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize\scshape\MakeLowercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize\scshape\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Section one}
\lipsum[1-5]
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\footnote{\lipsum[3]}
\section{Section two}
\lipsum[2-7]
\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\section{Section three}
\lipsum{1-5}
\footnote{\lipsum[8]}
\footnote{\lipsum[9]}
\section{Section four}
\lipsum{1-5}
\footnote{\lipsum[6]}
\markboth{\scshape note}{\scshape note}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Problem 1: in the header, "NOTE" appears not in scshape as well as the headers of the other pages.

Problem 2: I want to omit the title "Note" before the notes begin. But if I use `\renewcommand{\notesname}{}` I lack the header too, even if I put the code `\markboth{\scshape note}{\scshape note}` before the command to print endnotes.
Maybe, the troubles are connected... thanx

Comment: You have to add `\footnote{\lipsum[6]}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{} \addtoendnotes{\protect\markboth{Note}{Note}}`

Comment: Partially working: on p. 7 of my MWE there is no header at all (on p. 8 it seems all ok)

Comment: That is because the markboth is coming late since you are using lipsum. You have to put `\addtoendnotes{\protect\markboth{Note}{Note}}` some what early.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with the tag `\addtoendnotes`, and the modified codes are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

% notes
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand\enoteformat{%
   \noindent\theenmark.\ \hangindent 0\parindent%
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\theendnotes}{%
  \renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textsuperscript{\theenmark}\enspace}%
}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{} % <-------------------------------------
\let\footnote=\endnote
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}

% headers
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize\scshape\MakeLowercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize\scshape\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Section one}
\lipsum[1-5]
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\footnote{\lipsum[3]}
\section{Section two}
\lipsum[2-7]
\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\section{Section three}
\lipsum{1-5}
\footnote{\lipsum[8]}
\footnote{\lipsum[9]}
\section{Section four}
\lipsum{1-5}
\footnote{\lipsum[6]}
\addtoendnotes{\protect\markboth{\scshape note}{\scshape note}}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I apply `\def\notesname={\relax}` to take the notes title way.