# endnotes vs header text

Tags: endnotes

The `endnotes` package interferes with headers text, but only if the document has an odd number of pages. Here is a minimal working example:

---

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{endnotes}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}

\author{My Name}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}

First page

\endnotetext{first note}

\newpage

Second page

\endnotetext{second note}

\newpage

Third page

\endnotetext{third note}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

---

On the last page where the end notes are printed, the header becomes "Notes" instead of "My Title".  If however I remove the third page (or add a 4th one) then the header shows the author name (as it should be).

I believe that this is related to
[Endnotes and headers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225368/endnotes-and-headers)

I tried the two fixes there:  `\addtoendnotes{\protect\markboth{Note}{Note}}`  makes no difference and  `\def\notesname={\relax}`  crashes latex (unless I put it near the top of the file, in which case it makes no difference).

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\theendnotes` adds a mark when it executes the `\enoteheading` command which does the job of printing the header with `\notesname`. Without any other hook, the simple thing to do would be to redefine `\enoteheading` as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\enoteheading}{\section*{\notesname}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
```

Incidentally, your command `\def\notesname={\relax}` is actually defining `\notesname` with a template requiring `=` to follow it. The `=` doesn't belong there. In general, it's better to stick with the LaTeX commands for defining/redefining commands than to drop down to the plain TeX `\def`.

Comment: Redefining \enoteheading as explained by @DanHosek solved the problem.

Comment: For `amsart` I'd recommend also removing `\mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip`, which is useless as the class does indent the first paragraph after a title. Actually the package should do `\@afterindenttrue` instead of that concoction.

Comment: @egreg I'm flying blind at the moment since my laptop had to go back in for repairs so I don't have a working TeX system at the moment. I was going for minimal changes without paying attention to what stuff was doing.

Comment: @egreg `endnotes.sty` registers in it's changelog that the suggestion to use `\mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip` was by FMi. So I got curious, how would `\@afterindenttrue` be used here, just set it? Would it be as general or more general than the `\mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip`?

Comment: @gusbrs In general, I would prefer `\@afterindenttrue` over the `\mbox` incantation (yuopu would just replace the whole last line (except the closing brace) with `\@afterindenttrue`.  There are some edge cases where it might make a difference (e.g.., with a subsection immediately following a section), but that shouldn't apply here as near as I can tell from inspecting the source of endnotes.sty. Not sure why Frank chose that particular approach.

Comment: @DonHosek Thank you! Indeed, I've put some thought to it in the meantime and I also agree that `\@afterindenttrue` is a better approach. I'm actually working with another end notes package, but the situation is analogous, but slightly different. In the actual case, the whole end notes are grouped, so I can set locally exactly what `indentfirst` does, before any sectioning commands (which should catch an eventual `\chapter` too). It looks gook so far, let's hope I don't find any of the edge cases you mention. :-)